# How to create custom error pages with app.yaml for Google Appengine Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

For a Google Appengine project written in Python, I want to have my own error messages when an error occurs. I want to use the error_handlers as described in:
http://code.google.com/intl/nl/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Custom_Error_Responses

In the application I use webapp with `debug = False`

When I create an error in my code, I get the standard *500 Server error* message from the browser.

I have created a custom error page named `default_error.html`

The question is: Where to save this custom error page?

BTW This is my `app.yaml` code:

```
application: customerrorpage
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1


error_handlers:
- file: default_error.html

handlers:
- url: /good.htm
  static_files: static/good.htm
  upload: static/good.htm

- url: /
  static_files: static/good.htm
  upload: static/good.htm

- url: /.*
  script: main.py
```

Answer (score 4):

Defining a custom 404 with just the python part works for me:

`app.error_handlers[404] = handle_404`

```
def handle_404(request, response, exception):
    c = {'exception': exception.status}
    t = jinja2.get_jinja2(app=app).render_template('404.html', **c)
    response.write(t)
    response.set_status(exception.status_int)
```

This gives you more control over error messages and other dynamics that you might want to display.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However I do not need to define a custom 404 errorpage. I will simply accept all input and response to that in a neat way. That's the theory. In practice I could have made a program error, due to the fact that I don't have tested enough, or the project become that popular that an over_quota error occurs. My assumption was that all server errors (a 500 error) and all other Appengine specific server errors like over_quota are customisable with app.yaml. So the question is when I want to use yaml.app to handle this type of errors, where do I save my custom error_page?

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is to define a 'BaseRequestHandler' class, from which your request handlers are subclassed. 
The BaseRequestHandler class can override the handle_exception() method (see http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requesthandlerclass.html#RequestHandler_handle_exception) to render an error page.

Comment: What is the relation between the 'BaseRequestHandler' class and the use of app.yaml?

Answer (score 0):

Partly found how it works. Thank you all for your answers.

The location of the HTM file could be in the core or in a seperate directory. If that's the case use for example the following code in your app.yaml file:

```
error_handlers:
- file: error_handlers/default_error.html
```

The to be shown html file should now be placed in the directory error_handlers

When you import an nonexisting module in main.py the above page is shown.

To fetch a 500 error I used webapp2 to show a custom error page. This page is always shown when an error occurs. Even when there is an over_quota error and app.yaml is correctly configured. I also removed webapp2 and used webapp again. Now no page is displayed at all.

I have another app which is currently over_quote. How to get the over_quota html page displayed? Is it a bug?

Comment: You can add a filter to your error_handlers property. Over quota looks like, " - error_code: over_quota". You can add individual filters for quota, DoS protection and timeouts - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Custom_error_responses